# Why does assignment return the old value instead of the new one?

Tags: ponylang

Why does assignment return the previous value instead of the new value, re example: assigns `0` to `y` instead of `2`? This is dangerously unusual as it violates the principle of least surprise.

```
var x: I32 = 0
let y = (x = 2)
```

Comment: I can find a few references to the fact that this happens in the tutorial, but I cannot find any explanation as to *why* this happens. (Also, none of the mentions of the fact that it happens are in the section about variables and assignment.)

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, I'm mostly just head-scratching as to why this design decision was made and how it's used (or makes the implementation easier or more robust) in practice, because it seems code like `match (x = None) ...` isn't straightforward (the side-effect) and consistent as there are no compound assignment operators (i.e., `+=`) or increment (`x++`) either.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure this was done to get consistent results for `iso` variables.  Assignment to an `iso` variable would not be able to return the new value because that created an alias.  But it's true that a less surprising design would involve an assignment operator returning `None` and some other operation (swap?) for the recovery of the original value that is being overwritten.